# Filter polars dataframe using given time intervals

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

Saying I have 2 dataframes:

discount_dates

| product | discount_start_date | discount_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Iphone | 2012-12-31 | 2013-03-03 |
| Iphone | 2017-01-31 | 2019-12-03 |
| Macbook | 2013-02-22 | 2013-03-03 |
| Iwatch | 2012-12-31 | 2013-03-03 |
| Iwatch | 2013-12-31 | 2014-03-03 |
| Iwatch | 2014-12-31 | 2015-03-03 |

data_product

| product | date | n_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Iphone | 2013-03-01 | 1432 |
| Iphone | 2013-03-02 | 2314 |
| Iphone | 2013-03-03 | 3200 |
| Iphone | 2013-03-04 | 123 |
| Iphone | 2017-02-04 | 2230 |
| Iwatch | 2013-04-01 | 102 |
| Iwatch | 2013-04-02 | 12 |
| Iwatch | 2013-04-03 | 234 |

What I want is to compose a third dataframe based on `data_product` containing only rows where `date` is a discount date therefore contained between `discount_start_date` and `discount_end_date` of the `discount_dates` df.

result

| product | date | n_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Iphone | 2013-03-01 | 1432 |
| Iphone | 2013-03-02 | 2314 |
| Iphone | 2013-03-03 | 3200 |
| Iphone | 2017-02-04 | 2230 |

my approach in polars was the following:

```
import polars as pl

discount_dates = {
    "product": ["Iphone", "Iphone", "Macbook", "Iwatch", "Iwatch", "Iwatch"],
    "discount_start_date": ["2012-12-31", "2017-01-31", "2013-02-22", "2012-12-31", "2013-12-31", "2014-12-31"],
    "discount_end_date": ["2013-03-03", "2019-12-03", "2013-03-03", "2013-03-03", "2014-03-03", "2015-03-03"],
}

discount_dates = pl.DataFrame(discount_dates)

data_product = {
    "product": ["Iphone", "Iphone", "Iphone", "Iphone", "Iphone", "Iwatch", "Iwatch", "Iwatch"],
    "date": ["2013-03-01", "2013-03-02", "2013-03-03", "2013-03-04", "2017-02-04", "2013-04-01", "2013-04-02", "2013-04-03"],
    "n_sales": [1432, 2314, 3200, 123, 2230, 102, 12, 234],
}

data_product = pl.DataFrame(data_product)

discount_dates = discount_dates.groupby("product").agg(pl.col("discount_start_date").min(), pl.col("discount_end_date").max())
data_product = data_product.join(discount_dates, on="product")
promo_product = data_product.filter((pl.col("date").is_between(*["discount_start_date","discount_end_date"])))
```

Unfortunately though this doesn't take in consideration gaps among the discount intervals and in the example above `promo_product` ends up being equal to `data_product`. Is there a smart way to tackle this in polars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right approach, just you don't need to do any `groupby` at all in this operation. You want to join every possible discount window here.

I got the desired DataFrame with the code above by simply commenting out `discount_dates = ...` (and you can select just those three columns from there).

Comment: Wow! it was that simple actually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try (`pl_df1` contains discount dates and `pl_df2` contains product):

```py
# convert columns to datetime (if necessary):
pl_df1 = pl_df1.with_columns(
    pl.col("discount_start_date").str.to_datetime("%Y-%m-%d"),
    pl.col("discount_end_date").str.to_datetime("%Y-%m-%d"),
)

pl_df2 = pl_df2.with_columns(pl.col("date").str.to_datetime("%Y-%m-%d"))


# make new dataframe where we store all discount dates for each product in a list
discount_days_agg = pl_df1.groupby("product").agg(
    pl.apply(
        ["discount_start_date", "discount_end_date"],
        lambda x: pl.Series(pl.date_range(s, e, eager=True) for s, e in zip(*x)),
    )
)

# filter df2 with `discount_days_agg`
filtered_df2 = pl_df2.filter(
        pl.struct(["product", "date", "n_sales"]).apply(
            lambda x: any(
                x["date"] in dr
                for dr in discount_days_agg.row(
                    by_predicate=(pl.col("product") == x["product"])
                )[1]
            )
        )
)

print(filtered_df2)
```

Prints:

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────┐
│ product ┆ date                ┆ n_sales │
│ ---     ┆ ---                 ┆ ---     │
│ str     ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64     │
╞═════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════╡
│ Iphone  ┆ 2013-03-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1432    │
│ Iphone  ┆ 2013-03-02 00:00:00 ┆ 2314    │
│ Iphone  ┆ 2013-03-03 00:00:00 ┆ 3200    │
│ Iphone  ┆ 2017-02-04 00:00:00 ┆ 2230    │
└─────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────┘
```